# SQL query to Linq lambda

Tags: sql-server, linq

I have a table in SQL Server with following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable]
(
       [PatientId] [INT] NOT NULL, 
       [Timestamp] [DATETIME] NOT NULL,
       [FiO2] [TINYINT] NULL
)
```

and the following query, which groups by the on 5 minutes time difference and display the average of FiO2 and Timestamp per grouped data:

```
SELECT 
    AVG(FiO2) AS FiO2, 
    CAST(AVG(CAST([TimeStamp] AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) TimeStamp
FROM 
    MyTable
WHERE 
    PatientId = 97209520
GROUP BY 
    DATEADD(MINUTE, DATEDIFF(MINUTE,'2019-03-13 12:08:52.447',[TimeStamp]) / 5 * 5, 0)
```

**Here is the sample data:**

[image]

**Here is the result of my SQL query:**

[image]

**I have used this linQ query**

```
var averagedData = loadedData.GroupBy(t => new {
                    t.PatientId, 
                    TimeBracket = new DateTime(t.TimeStamp.Year, t.TimeStamp.Month, t.TimeStamp.Day, t.TimeStamp.Hour, t.TimeStamp.Minute,0).AddMinutes(5 - t.TimeStamp.Minute % 5)
                })
                .Select(p => new MonitorData{
                    PatientId = p.Key.PatientId,
                    FiO2 = (byte) p.Average(q => q.FiO2),
                    TimeStamp = new DateTime((long) p.Average(t => t.TimeStamp.Ticks), p.Key.TimeBracket.Kind)
                })
                .ToList();
```

for some reason it returns 5 records rather the 4 with different calculated values. for some reason it groups the first 2 rows into a group and the rest in 4 other groups and then calculate the average.

Comment: Have you tried it by yourself? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to figure out how to do this as a completely native LINQ to SQL query, but if we do the grouping, then pull the result into memory with `.AsEnumerable()`, we can then create the averages...

## Second Edit

This is the LINQ to match the output of the query supplied in the question. It rounds each record to the nearest 5 minutes, and perserves seconds and milliseconds data.

```
  var averagedData = loadedData
    .GroupBy(t => new
    {
      t.PatientId,
      TimeBracket = new DateTime(t.TimeStamp.Year, t.TimeStamp.Month, t.TimeStamp.Day, t.TimeStamp.Hour, (int)Math.Round(t.TimeStamp.Minute / 5.0) * 5, t.TimeStamp.Second, t.TimeStamp.Millisecond)
    })
    .Select(g => new MonitorData
    {
      PatientId = g.Key.PatientId,
      FiO2 = (byte) g.Average(p => p.FiO2),
      TimeStamp = new DateTime((long) g.Average(t => t.TimeStamp.Ticks), g.Key.TimeBracket.Kind)
    }).ToList();
```

==================================

**Edit**

This version should work with NHibernate, but it means loading all appropriate patient rows into memory, then doing the calculations:

```
var averaged =
  table.Where(x => x.PatientId == 2)
       .AsEnumerable()
       .GroupBy(t => new
       {
         t.PatientId,
         TimeBracket =
         new DateTime(t.TimeStamp.Year, t.TimeStamp.Month, t.TimeStamp.Day, t.TimeStamp.Hour, t.TimeStamp.Minute,
           0).AddMinutes(5 - t.TimeStamp.Minute % 5)
       })
       .Select(g => new MyTable
       {
         PatientId = g.Key.PatientId,
         FiO2 = (byte) g.Average(p => p.FiO2),
         TimeStamp = new DateTime((long) g.Average(t => t.TimeStamp.Ticks), g.Key.TimeBracket.Kind)
       }).ToList();
```

==================================

This assumes you have EntityFramework in your project and have access to `DbFunctions`:

```
var averaged = 
    table.Where(x => x.PatientId == 97209520)
    .GroupBy(t => new {
        t.PatientId,
        t.TimeStamp,
        TimeBracket = DbFunctions.AddMinutes(DbFunctions.CreateDateTime(t.TimeStamp.Year, t.TimeStamp.Month, t.TimeStamp.Day, t.TimeStamp.Hour, t.TimeStamp.Minute, 0), 5 - t.TimeStamp.Minute % 5).Value
    })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(g => new MyTable
    {
        PatientId = g.Key.PatientId,
        FiO2 = (byte) g.Average(p => p.FiO2),
        TimeStamp = new DateTime((long) g.Average(t => t.TimeStamp.Ticks), g.Key.TimeBracket.Kind)
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: The project is using NHibernate. Anyway that I could load all data from DB into memory and then apply the group by on it?

Comment: Thank you very much for this! it nearly works but not quite there. Would you please have a look at my updated question and give me your thoughts?

Comment: No problem :) My answer behaves slightly differently to yours - it rounds up the time to the next 5 minute window so created 5 groups. As your groups have milliseconds in, they get rounded up too (15.52.447 -> 20).

08/09 -> 10
10-14 -> 15
15-19 -> 20
20-24 -> 25
25-29 -> 30

Your datediff only checks the minutes, and ignores seconds / milliseconds which is why you're getting different results. Do you want it to behave exactly as your query?

Comment: Yes I need to have the Time bracket begins from the beginning in interval of 5 minutes. BTW, If I change the interval from 5 minutes to either 15, 30 or 60 minutes (or any interval bigger than 14 minutes) the query throws Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow. exception! It is basically the second part of the query where it calculates the Average of the TimeStamp. So, I have changed it to `TimeStamp = new DateTime((long)p.Average(t => t.TimeStamp.Ticks / 10000) * 10000, p.Key.TimeBracket.Kind)` as a workaround